# How does Mathematica compute real and complex solutions to single, non-polynomial equations?

Tags: numerical-analysis, algorithms, nonlinear-equations, rootfinding

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46892953/how-to-solve-a-polynomial-with-multiple-solutions-including-complex-solutions) on StackOverflow has led me to ask myself what would be involved in solving an equation like this one using tools available to the Python programmer.
$$ \frac{0.125567841}{d^{2.25}} = \frac{2.513274d+0.10053+2.11\pi}{d+0.04}$$

What are the fundamental numerical tools that one would use to get the one real and four complex roots of this equation ([WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+0.12556841%2Fd%5E2.25+%3D+(2.513274+d+%2B+0.10053%2B2.11+pi)%2F(d+%2B+0.04)+for+d))? I have looked (hard) at the Mathematica documentation but cannot discern what they might be. It's probably mainly ignorance on my part.

Comment: Numerically or symbolically?

Comment: @rubenvb: Either way. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Does Mathematica solve this symbolically?

Comment: Mathematica is a proprietary closed-source software package, so there is no documentation that is freely available about "how" Mathematica does most things.  There is abundant literature on root-finding methods for polynomials, both symbolically and numerically, and study of such algorithms will likely prove to be a rewarding project.  However as a "black box" we cannot be sure at a low level how Mathematica accomplishes either of these.

Comment: @nicoguaro: In case you're asking me, I don't know.

Comment: @hardmath: Thanks for your comments. I can live with uncertainty though! :) One of things that interests me — and that surprised me — about this example is that Wolfram-Alpha somehow seems confident that it has identified all of the roots for a non-polynomial equation. I thought perhaps that someone on this forum might recognise what the software is doing.

Comment: Over the reals, that equation seems to have just one solution. This is because it is not defined for negative $d$ and the limit $d\rightarrow \infty$ is about 1256637/500000.

Comment: This particular equation can be rewritten in polynomial form, so it is  perhaps not such a mystery as may have first appeared.   Would that serve as substantially an Answer?

Comment: @hardmath: In my question, I confessed ignorance. I should have mentioned being thick as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rewrite with integer exponents through a change of variable. This looks like $d=x^r$ where $r$ is the LCM of the denominator of the rationalized exponents. In your case we have $r=4$ and:

$$6.72427 - 0.125568 x^4 + 2.51327 x^{13}=0$$

Which can be solved in the usual ways. In *Mathematica* there is a clear distinction between symbolic and numerical solutions. You have floating point numbers bouncing around, so the solution that pops out is a result of numerical approximation. These are described in their extended internal documentation: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SomeNotesOnInternalImplementation.html#2118

The 13 roots lie along a circle in the complex plane:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

As the other Answer already touches on the possibility of a symbolic root-solver being applied to this particular equation (by transforming into a polynomial form, albeit of degree $\ge 5$), I'll make some remarks about numerical root-finding.

When we want to find *real roots* of a *continuous function*, the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) is a basic tool.  On a closed bounded interval where the real function is continuous and *changes sign* between endpoints, there will be a real root somewhere in the interior of that interval.  The [Bisection Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) allows us to approximate at least one such root in that interval.

Here we can transform the equation into finding roots of a real continuous function by cross-multiplying and collecting terms on one side:

$$ \frac{0.125567841}{d^{2.25}} = \frac{2.513274d+0.10053+2.11\pi}{d+0.04} $$

$$ 0.125567841(d+0.04) = (2.513274d+0.10053+2.11\pi)d^{2.25} $$

$$ F(d) \equiv 2.513274d^{3.25} + (0.10053+2.11\pi)d^{2.25} - 0.125567841d - 0.00502271364 = 0 $$

This form of the problem is easier to analyze, but we should check whether the cross-multiplication introduced [artifact roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/594086/3111), i.e. roots for the revised equation that do not satisfy the original equation.  When we multiply both sides by the denominators $d^{2.25}$ and $d+0.04$, it is possible that this introduces one or more new roots where such factors are zero, i.e. where $d=0$ or $d=-0.04$.  Fortunately $F(0)\neq 0$ and $F(-0.04)\neq 0$, so we have *not* introduced artifact roots in this case.

One should be careful to define what (if anything) $d^{2.25}$ means for *negative* real values of $d$.  Inevitably one must abandon any *real value* for this expression because it requires taking square roots of a negative number.  This is a particular weakness of relying on tools such as Wolfram Alpha, because it attempts to be helpful by aggressively assuming that *some sense* is to be made of the expression even for negative arguments $d$.

Fortunately in this case what roots Wolfram Alpha finds are *not* on the negative half of the real axis for $d$.  There is a positive real root $d\approx 0.06087$, and the other roots found are in complex conjugate pairs.

The real root can be found by standard methods such as bisection once we realize that $F(d)$ is continuous and changes sign on the interval $[0,1]$.  That is, $F(0)=-0.00502271364$ and $F(1)\approx 9.11197$, so there must be an intermediate value of $d_0$ where the function $F(d_0)=0$.  Once the location of the root $d_0$ is suitably narrowed by bisection, etc., more rapidly converging methods (like Newton's method) can be used.

When a function like $F(d)$ with real coefficients on rational powers has complex roots, these will occur naturally in complex conjugate pairs.  One can then replace the *one dimensional* search for a real root with a *two dimensional* search for a complex conjugate root pair $d = x \pm iy$.  A classic approach to this is [Bairstow's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bairstow%27s_method), which uses Newton-Raphson iterations to locate a complex conjugate root pair using only real arithmetic.

Just as Python users interested in symbolic root-finding should be familiar with `sympy`, those interested in numerical root-finding will be attracted to the `numpy` library.  In many problems a synthesis of the two approaches is advantageous, e.g. using `sympy` to get derivatives of a function which can be evaluated by routines in `numpy`.